# Using selenium to automate kendoUI numeric text box, without javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui

I have a scenario, in which I have to automate a page full of kendoUI's numeric text box.

I'm able to locate the element using `xpath or id selector`, however when selenium tries to input the value in the said text box it receives exceptions such as:

> ElementNotVisibleException => when tried to click on the said element.
>
> InvalidElementStateException => when tried to input the value using
>   sendKeys

I'm looking for a solution which could automate this task without using `ExecuteJavascript interface`.

Below is the sample `html` of one of such textbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sheet_width">Page Width<span class="ep-required-label" ng-show="sheet_maintenance_form.sheet_width.$error.required" aria-hidden="false" style="">*</span>
    </label>
    <span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
        <span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default">
            <input type="text" class="k-formatted-value ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid k-input" title="" tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="999.999" aria-disabled="false" style="display: inline-block;">
            <input ng-required="true" kendo-numeric-text-box="sheet_width" k-options="sheet_edit_controller.sheet_field_options" ng-model="sheet_edit_controller.sheet_config.sheet_width" name="sheet_width" id="sheet_width" class="k-input ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" type="text" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="999.999" aria-disabled="false" required="required" aria-invalid="true" style="display: none;">
            <span class="k-select">
                <span unselectable="on" class="k-link k-link-increase" aria-label="Increase value" title="Increase value">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-up"/>
                </span>
                <span unselectable="on" class="k-link k-link-decrease" aria-label="Decrease value" title="Decrease value">
                    <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"/>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me to increase the value in the box by 1 but I appreciate any other suggestions:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Browser);
actions.MoveToElement(
Container.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.k-i-arrow-n"))).Click().Perform()
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. It worked!!! The trick was to click on one of the arrow button, which in turn changes the state of the input text field.

Comment: Yeah poorly described by me sorry for that but I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who hits their head on this wall, this is how I resolved it on my side.

Kendo turns a numeric textbox into 2 textboxes, only the second has the id you set and you can't go straight to it as it isn't visible so in my property declaration I have the following

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "MyNumberField")]
private IWebElement myRealNumberField;
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "(.//*[@id='MyNumberField']/preceding::input[1])")]
private IWebElement myNumberField;
```

And then in the code

```
myNumberField.Click(); //This then causes the real number field to appear
myRealNumberField.Click();
myRealNumberField.SendKeys("Stackoverflow Example");
```

Hope it saves some people a few hours